# Using Oracle SQL syntax for custom developed database server

Tags: sql

Is it possible to implement own database server taking Oracle PL/SQL syntax as the bases or i would like to ask why different database solutions have different syntax eg: SQL server, MySql, Sqlite etc. can't they have some specific standard of syntax for basic operations including PL/SQL(excluding SQLite) why everyone is having a different syntax, sorry for diversion of question into patent issues but i could not find a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, but you have to parse the PL/SQL yourself into something other platforms understand. (You can use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for example as parser tool. There is even a [full featured grammar for PL/SQL](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser)) This is possible for small solutions with a small instruction set, but for large, full support of PL/SQL you need to be Oracle-sized.

To answer the why: two reasons:

1. There is no standard, so everyone picks his own;
2. You don't want customers to leave, so your own 'best' framework that is incompatible with others, that is your USP, and it prevents users from just porting their code to the other platform. They are stuck on yours.

Comment: There is for example the SQL-92 standard, but usually technology is way ahead of the standards, and it's too difficult to back-port the syntax. The same thing happens in HTML only it is waaaaay worse. I'm glad I'm a DB programmer not a web programmer.

Comment: SQL-92 doesn't describe PL/SQL or any related language. 'Just' SQL.

Comment: I understood the USP proposition but why an open source db like MySQL uses this proposition because ultimately its tiring for masses who are keep switching the solution because of syntax and technological differences otherwise users will lure in easily to an open source solution and solutions like MySQl will prevail over other commercial databases and will be healthier for open source environment from growth perspective as well, we can say MySql for instance would become Java of databases.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that PL/SQL and others are copyrighted. You can't just copy them.

Comment: I am not asking to plagiarize but just to keep the most of the basic and intermediate level tasks with a standard syntax, for instance i found Fyracle a Firebird fork giving somewhat similar approach but still its yet to see a full oracle 10g command set support, but if it happens will become a miracle in database industry.

Comment: But still there is no standard, and people always tend to think they can do better.

Comment: we need a standard to support open source softwares and can always hope contradiction in commercial software(so let it be its for best), just taking an example of an English language we can understand how its easy for us to communicate people across the globe and we do not have to pay for it whether its a commercial talk or casual talk.

Comment: Well, developers want to, but that commercial guy... ;)

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I think you misunderstand me. In response to original question "can't they have some specific standard of syntax for basic operations" and your statement "There is no standards, so everyone picks his own", I maintain that SQL-92 is a "standard". PL/SQL doesn't implement it fully. Neither does anything else but it _is_ a standard.

Comment: But OP is talking about PL/SQL which is something different than SQL. Well, they live in the same DB, that's about it.